# AngularJs + Typescript: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-types

I'm trying to combine Angular1.5 + Typescript.
Installed needed types:

`npm install @types/angularjs`

but still see the error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'

Already tried different options:

```
import 'angular';
import 'angularjs'; //that is name inside @types
import angular from 'angularjs';
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

I'm using:

```
"ts-loader": "1.0.0",
"typescript": "2.0.7",
"webpack": "1.13.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
```

**tsconfig** is pretty standard:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

already simplified **webpack** config as much as possible:
    var webpack = new require('webpack');

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: './index.ts',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {loaders: [{test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader'},]},
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },

  plugins: [new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()],

  devtool: 'source-map',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
  }
};
```

And I also simplified **index.ts** itself, to focus only on type import:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
angular.module('testmodule', []);
```

**UPD**: tsconfig.json. Added typeRoots option.

Now getting new errors:

> ERROR in .../node_modules/@types/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts
>   (6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'.
>
> ERROR in .../node_modules/@types/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts
>   (65,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IServiceProvider'.
>
> ERROR in .../node_modules/@types/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts
>   (122,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IScope'.
>
> ERROR in .../node_modules/@types/angularjs/index.d.ts
>   (66,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.

Comment: Could you show your directory structure and tsconfig file? Also if you are using a tool like Webpack or SystemJS show it's configs as well.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, updated my question

Comment: Try to add `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]` to `"compilerOptions"` within your tsconfig;

Comment: ok, now I have new errors

Comment: I've made some tests and figured it. Checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40421638/4488121

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can't see any answer to this question though..

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

if you run this in the command line it should fix the issue.

```
npm install @types/angular
```

What's annoying about this fix is that for some reason it doesn't update your package.json.. However if you add the following to your dependencies within package.json **instead** of the above it should fix the issue and have the package.json mirror your packages.

```
"@types/angular": "1.6.5",
"@types/jquery": "2.0.40",
```

Comment: `for some reason it doesn't update your package.json` – add `--save` flag in order to save it in your package.json

Comment: from npm5, npm will --save by default.